# Could I track a link from my app using Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, outbound

I'm a developer and started do study Google Analytics and I need help

I am creating an app with link to partner stores and I need to know if a sale was generated through my app.

I have a list of products from different stores, each one with a link to be purchased on an external website. I'll receive a commission for each sale originating from my app and I need to track this information in order to be able to charge my partners assertively.

Exists any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UTM parameters in querystring (add campaign parameters to URLs) so you can track Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

You can use this tool, Campaign URL Builder: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/